# Skipping columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**The problem**

In column M I want to write names I have written in column B, these names are not alphabetical and have to be written manualy "=Bxx". In the column beside (Column N) I want to write a value from column F, from the same row.

So far I have done it manually "=Bxx", next column, "=Fxx", new row "=Byy", next column "=Fyy". I get the hunch that there must be an elegant way of doing that automatically.

Comment: So you want a duplicate list, but in alphabetical order?

Comment: A little confused by what you are trying to do here, perhaps you can upload some dummy data?

Comment: In row M I have the following values: "=B3", "=B6", "=B18", "=B26", "=B25", "=B27", "=B29", "=B32" etc.

For each B-cell there is a corresponding F-cell which I want to print in Row N.

Right now I do it manually, but I believe there is maybe a simple way to automate. Basically I want to replace B with F in "=Bxx"

Comment: I'm note sure if you can see this Google Sheets? It's in the Sheet "Spiller rank" and then it is row N and O (I added one since I wrote this question)
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DWTw4qO8EyY8VlRkcI98E_gCkwxN2lP242rr34uix5o/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy data from column B to column M, you've done it with your "=Bx"
To copy column F into column N, you just do the same and both are real quick...

If you double click on the bottom right corner of your cell containing the formula, it will reproduce the formula on the entire column. (or if you click, hold and drag down that corner).

Comment: The problem is that the "=Bx" is not consistent, it might be that it is
"=B34", "=B36", "=B29", "=B25" etc. And for each B I want to write the value for the corresponding F. So in this case "=F34", "=F36", "=F29", "=F25" etc

Comment: just do it for one and double click on the bottom right corner

Comment: so let's say you're talking about line 2:
in M2 you write =B2 and drag the formula down

Comment: (you click and hold the bottom right corner of the cell and drag aaaaalll the way down)
(or double click on that corner)